# Why 5<4<2 is returning true?

Tags: javascript, comparison

I am practicing Javascript. I came across one scenario where I am comparing 3 numbers as below:

> console.log(5<4<2);

It returns true. Now that I don't understand why. By operator precendence it must evaluate left to right which means **false<2**. Is something strange done by js in this case?

Comment: The comparison: `(5 < 4) < 2 => false < 2 => 0 < 2 == true`.

Comment: The numeric value of `false` is `0`.

Comment: So, what do you expect the value of `false<2` to be then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the [***`Operator precedence`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

[**`Less than (<)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Less_than_operator) operator is evaluated from ***left-to-right***.

First `5<4` is evaluated to `false` then `false` is converted to `0` in the next evaluation. Finally `0<2` is evaluated to true

```js
console.log(5<4);// false
console.log(0<2);// true
```

Comment: why is it converted to 0?

Comment: @VinayPrajapati, being the right operand is a number the left operand is coerced (convert) to the number type and the number type of `false` is `0`:)